# port forward with iptables and debian

Tags: linux, iptables

I've a lan, a server and a VM

```
lan: 192.168.50.0/24
linux server: 192.168.50.3
linux VM guest: 192.168.50.1 (with apache)
```

I want that linux server redirect all requests from lan and port 80 to 192.168.50.1:80

I use these without results :-/

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.50.1:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.50.1 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s 192.168.50.1 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

ip_forward is 1
```

Comment: I don't see the point why you would want to do something like this. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Hello, in my lan I've some services (ssh, apache, postfix on VM 192.168.50.1). I'd like that all clients can connect to these services. Lan is connected to 192.168.50.3. thanks

Comment: How is your VM network set up?

Comment: bridge mode. Lan can see VM

Comment: In that case you just access the service with IP address and port from the other computers on the network. You don't need any NAT performed here.

Comment: I know, but from outside I need forward. The server in connected to internet.

Comment: Then you need to set up the NAT in your router so that it forwards packets arriving on its external interface to your internal network IP address.

Comment: I've a modem, what I need is that all external clients can connect to VM via server :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50256/discussion-between-tero-kilkanen-and-pol-hallen).

Answer (score 2):

In your setup, port forwarding is not normally required.  (There a very small number of situations that require what is known as Hairpin NAT, where NAT is used internally, but this does not apprear to be the case from what you have described)

Port forwarding is used where the internal, non globally routable (RFC1918) hosts share a limited number (often just one) publicly routable IP address (known as non-RFC1918).   Native Address Translation, NAT (aka Masquerading) is used to make this work.  Your address prefix, 192.168.x.x is part of RFC1918.

Port forwarding is used in the sutuation where clients on the public internet need to access hosts behind NAT through a firewall.

In your case all your hosts are RFC1918 and are on the same network, so NAT is not required.  You just need to correctly configure the IP networking.

The PREROUTING and POSTROUTING rules in the NAT table are for native address translation, which you don't need.

Assuming you have the VM configured as a bridge, and your network topology is correct, your hosts share the same IPV4 LAN (192.168.50.0/24).  Because of this there is no need to have a router in your system, so the FORWARD rule is not required. Forward rules only make sense on a router where IP forwarding is enabled.

Unless you have misconfigured your network, or omitted information from your question, the simple answer is that all your clients in the IP range 192.168.50.2 to 192.168.50.254 should be able to access 192.168.50.1 without any need to involve iptables.